# Where is the key to get out of the Catacombs in Hatred Symbolized?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I think this may actually be a bug in my game but I want to make sure that I'm not missing something.

I have finished the Hatred Symbolized quest in Chapter 2 of The Witcher 2 following Roche's path. I am in the Catacombs where I meet Saskia and Zoltan. Saskia gives me the sword I need to complete the quest. There is a locked door behind them that I *should* be able to access at this point.

I looted the corpse in the main room and received a catacomb key. I have tried the door after acquiring this key and it still says it's locked. Should this key unlock that door or is there another key that I missed along the way? If so, what is the catacomb key actually for?

Comment: If the door says "locked" instead of "Key Required" you will never be able to go through the door, short of a quest unlocking it for you. If the door is coming up "locked" after the cinema scene, I think you've got the wrong door.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize there was a difference between 'locked' and 'key required'. Back to searching this horrible catacomb maze for another door (or the entrance, which I also can't find at this point :/ )

Comment: keep a finger on your Aard sign. There are quite a few walls that can be blown open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the path to the Saskia and Zoltan, what you have to do is just **go back the same way**.

The door behind them is used for ***Vergen Besieged***

An acquired key is for the door marked with **7**, really not sure why there is a door protecting a few monsters.

Other marks:

- **1** Pontar Valley
- **2** Bullvore
- **3** Zoltan and Saskia – connected with Hatred Symbolized.
- **4** Adam Pangratt and the mercenaries – connected with Vergen Besieged.
- **5** Dethmold and Adam Pangratt – connected with Vergen Besieged.
- **6** Vergen exit – accessible only during Vergen Besieged.
- **!** Nekkers, Rotfiends

[image: Map of the catacombs]

Comment: The locked door isn't just hiding a few monsters, there's a pair of leggings in a chest as well.